# how can I attach screws perpendicularly to an aluminum sheet

Tags: screws, aluminum

I do not own a drill press nor a welding machine; I do own a simple drill however it is not poweful enough to penetrate through the aluminum. are there any special glue types for aluminum that can help me with that?

Comment: How thick is the aluminum you're trying to get thru? And please reword your question as it's not very clear as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "attach perpendicularly"?  It also isn't clear why you can't drill aluminum; it's very soft.  But if you can't drill a hole, what's the purpose of the screw?  Which end of the screw do you need to attach to the aluminum?  What kinds of forces and in what direction does the attachment need to withstand?  How big are the screw and aluminum?  Can the whole process be done in a shop or does this need to be done somewhere on-site?  Are there any constraints, like limits on heat?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "simple drill" is this an electric drill or hand-powered? If it's electric you should be able to drill into it with a decent drill bit. You can *generally use woodworking tools (saws, drills, files, etc) on aluminum, unless you have some sort of exotic hardened aluminum.

You can use epoxy to join aluminum. Make sure both surfaces are clean and dry. A little scuffing with sandpaper would help it get a better grip.

This is dependent on the use for the item, also. If it is not highly stressed,  you should be fine.

*generally, as in not EVERY single wood working tool.